# asp.net hash table vulnerability

Tags: asp.net, iis, hash

On the 28/12/2011 US-CERT released a bulletin about the majority of web servers being vulnerable to DOS attacks due to the way they handle hash table collisions. Article [here](http://www.securityweek.com/hash-table-collision-attacks-could-trigger-ddos-massive-scale)

Could someone please explain where this hash table fits in to the ASP.NET lifecycle? Is it one hash table per session or one big hash table per server instance?

Thank you,
Fidel

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/12/28/asp-net-security-update-shipping-thursday-dec-29th.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash table in question is `Request.Form`.

The server parses the form data and places the key-value pairs into the `Request.Form` collection. If the form data contains keys that produce the same hash code, it produces hash collisions which reduces the performance of the hash table.

So, it's not one table per server or per session, but one table per POST request.

Comment: I think the underlying flaw is on all Hash tables though :| so it'll be more than just a once per post request. The biggest hit is normally using POST but if a app makes use of hash tables internally then it'll affect that too will it not?

Comment: @JohnMitchell: It's only if you create the hash table using keys from the request data that it's vunerable to DoS attacks. If you create a hash table from other data, it's not affected by the input.

Comment: But if you parse user input and theres duplicates (ie any data which would cause a bucket collision) then this could be used as a DDos, the failure is in the time it takes for collisions to be handled. So whilst the article specifically talks about POST as a vector other vectors could be easily used.

Comment: @JohnMitchell: Yes, but as I said, only if you use keys from the request data. So, that's practically only if you reinvent the `Request.Form` collection.

Answer (score 0):

A hashtable will be used throughout the application its not just in once place.  For example when you add post variables to a page they get processed internally in a hashtable, so if you had a massive amount of hashtable collisions (ie post variables with the same name on a page it'd happen here). Its a very efficient memory storage system for accessing a "array" using a collection of words (think of a dictionary).

This is one of these things, whilst it can be exploited, the better thing to do is use best practises and monitor CPU usage, limit maximum POST Size per page, and limit requests from a single host.

Comment: Sorry just added, its a hashtable per data type, so it will be one for each type of data that uses it, so its going to be used a lot more than just a per-session its per page and per data item on the page that requires a dictionary style object. Think of a hashtable just like an array if you want to see how often its used..